# Canon printer driver: low DPI

Tags: printer, dpi, ppd

My printer (Canon G7050) can print up to  4800 x 1200 dpi. However, the linux driver I got from Canon is set to 600 dpi only:

```
*OpenUI *Resolution/Output Resolution: PickOne
*de.Translation Resolution/Output Resolution: PickOne: ""
*fr.Translation Resolution/Output Resolution: PickOne: ""
*zh.Translation Resolution/Output Resolution: PickOne: ""
*ja.Translation Resolution/Output Resolution: PickOne: ""
*DefaultResolution: 600dpi
*Resolution 600dpi/600 dpi: "<</HWResolution[600 600]>>setpagedevice"
*de.Resolution 600dpi/600 dpi: "<</HWResolution[600 600]>>setpagedevice": ""
*fr.Resolution 600dpi/600 dpi: "<</HWResolution[600 600]>>setpagedevice": ""
*zh.Resolution 600dpi/600 dpi: "<</HWResolution[600 600]>>setpagedevice": ""
*ja.Resolution 600dpi/600 dpi: "<</HWResolution[600 600]>>setpagedevice": ""
*CloseUI: *Resolution
```

- Could you confirm that I lose potential printing quality with this PPD?
- Can I manually add new DPI settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual specifications say that "Ink droplets can be placed with a minimum pitch of 1/4800 inch". It doesn't say "Ink droplets are **no more than** 1/4800 inches across". See https://www.canon.co.uk/printers/pixma-g7050/specifications/

It is unlikely that you will be able to tell if there is a difference. The only way would be to print a test page (on some expensive high quality paper) on a very expensive top-end printer and compare it carefully with one produced on your printer.

Note that a standard monitor probably manages 100-200dpi.